# How do I have my plugin fire before another in docpad so I can preprocess the content?

Tags: docpad

I would like to create a plugin which preprocesses content like markdown before it is passed to marked.

I don't want to create yet another extension to tack on the filename but would rather just search for a pattern in the content and if found do a substitution before marked has a chance to render.

I tried using the `render` event but my plugin seems to fire after marked even though its name sorts below it. What order do the plugins get used in?

I also tried using a `renderBefore` event but I can't figure out how to manipulate the content from there.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Jeff

Comment: Is there a way to set the priority of a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a plugin.priority will affect the order in which plugins are called with greater priorities being executed first.

The default plugin priority is 500.

Comment: You can also do `#{eventName}Priority: 501` to set the priority just for that one event. E.g. `renderBeforePriority: 501` to set the priority just for the `renderBefore` event.